# Which template tag to include an image stored using django-storage[dropbox]

Tags: django, django-storage

I try to build my first application with Django, and use django-storage to store my media on dropbox:

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.dropbox.DropBoxStorage'
DROPBOX_OAUTH2_TOKEN = ---- mytoken ----
DROPBOX_ROOT_PATH = 'media'
```

It works well to upload and display the images using the models directly (e.g. `{{ object.photo.url }}` in the html template works)

However, how can I create a link to the image in the template if I have no object.

Something like

```
<img  src="{{media_url}}myimage.jpg">
```

does not work as it links to localhost (on my local server). Is it needed to redefine *media_url* or is there another tag to use?

Comment: I think relative paths should work...

Comment: I try to have a dropbox link, starting with https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/apitl/. I guess there is a call to the storage module needed somewhere. It is done automatically for model objects.

Comment: Either you have to send media_url to your template 
or you can have a view and 
```path('media/', <views func>, name='media_server')```
and  use this template tag in your template
```{% url 'media_server' %}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about the existence of any tag to use in the case of accessing the image from dropbox. I would solve this issue using custom `filters` in Django since it is the case of distinguishing between `local` and `remote` and forming the right `URL` to pass to the `src` attribute.

You can read from the [docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters) on how custom `filter` works. Essentially, you would need a custom function that prepends the remote/local `URL`.

Using a function like this for e.g.

```
@register.filter
@stringfilter
def prepend(str):
    url = "" #defien your remote url here
    return "{}{}".format(url, str)
```

You then make calls from the template to this function which would give you the correct url (as you defined it).

Comment: Thanks! I got it to work using a filter with the followning line inside: return storage.url(str)